# EXCEL 2016 Adding Extra Columns to file when Saved as a .csv File

Tags: excel

I have [this .csv file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9lwnbcdj42htfbj/Example.csv?dl=0) that I created from an EXCEL 2016 spreadsheet. This file does not work when I try and upload it to an online web service I use because there are extra columns at the end of the file which can be seen when the .csv file is opened in Notepad:

[image]

I have tried now many, many times to manually delete the extra columns in EXCEL and then re-save the file, but the extra columns remain. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you still have a lot of empty columns without knowing. So, you need to select the column next to your last column with the data (in your case seems like 5th column or column E should be the one), press down ctrl + shift + right arrow key (that way you are selecting all the columns to the right). Now that all these columns are selected, right click on the header of one of these selected columns (doesn't matter which) and "Delete". Then save and you should be good.

If that didn't help, try the instruction on [this](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/823-excel-delete-multiple-empty-columns.html) link.

Comment: I had done this all the way to column HQ with no result, but ctrl+shift+right arrow key did the trick. Many thanks!!